# R sample from sequence stepwise vs replicate with different results

Tags: r, replication, sample

**EDIT**  (completely revised question as requested)

I get some unexpected behavior when sampling one index from a sequence stepwise vs sampling the whole sequence. If I set seed once

```
set.seed(123)
```

and execute

```
sample(c(0.9,0.95,1,1.01,1.02,1.03,1.04,1.05))
```

I get e.g.

```
[1] 1.03 0.90 1.02 1.00 0.95 1.04 1.05 1.01  
[1] 1.05 0.95 1.01 1.04 0.90 1.00 1.03 1.02   
[1] 0.90 1.04 1.01 1.05 1.00 0.95 1.03 1.02
```

However, if I repeatedly execute (very often, e.g. 100 times)

```
sample(c(0.9,0.95,1,1.01,1.02,1.03,1.04,1.05))[3]
```

R will never sample anything but 0.9, 0.95, 1 or 1.0. I also changed the seed but behavior is the same. What am I missing?

R version 3.1.3 (2015-03-09)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

Comment: Cannot reproduce (didn't expect to either). There is always a chance you can get a long run with random numbers.

Comment: Ok. well this is a really long run then (even with fresh R). I was just struck by the fact that he never sampled anything from above mentioned numbers consistently.

Comment: What does "never" sample mean exactly? How many numbers did you choose before concluding you would never see the value?

Comment: Are you doing `set.seed()` at any point?

Comment: more than a 100 times (each) in 3 fresh R sessions.

Comment: yes set.seed but also changed it and seeing the numbers coming up in replicate way, I see no reasons why they shouldn't come up in stepwise execution.

Comment: `set.seed(4); sample(seq(from = 0.9, to = 1.1, by = 0.01), size=1, replace=T)[1]` gives 1.02 on my system.

Comment: ok. somehow my assumption was that if I see the numbers in replicate, I would expect them in stepwise execution as replicate is not more than a convenience function around stepwise execution. But given that question was downgraded, this was apparently deemed stupid.

Answer (score 1):

No repro:

```
> set.seed(123)
> sample(seq(from = 0.9, to = 1.1, by = 0.01), size=1, replace=T)[1]
[1] 0.96
> sample(seq(from = 0.9, to = 1.1, by = 0.01), size=1, replace=T)[1]
[1] 1.06
> sample(seq(from = 0.9, to = 1.1, by = 0.01), size=1, replace=T)[1]
[1] 0.98
> sample(seq(from = 0.9, to = 1.1, by = 0.01), size=1, replace=T)[1]
[1] 1.08
> sample(seq(from = 0.9, to = 1.1, by = 0.01), size=1, replace=T)[1]
[1] 1.09
> sample(seq(from = 0.9, to = 1.1, by = 0.01), size=1, replace=T)[1]
[1] 0.9
> sample(seq(from = 0.9, to = 1.1, by = 0.01), size=1, replace=T)[1]
[1] 1.01
> sample(seq(from = 0.9, to = 1.1, by = 0.01), size=1, replace=T)[1]
[1] 1.08
> sample(seq(from = 0.9, to = 1.1, by = 0.01), size=1, replace=T)[1]
[1] 1.01
> sample(seq(from = 0.9, to = 1.1, by = 0.01), size=1, replace=T)[1]
[1] 0.99
```

And:

```
> set.seed(123)
> replicate(10,sample(seq(from = 0.9, to = 1.1, by = 0.01), size=1, replace=T))
 [1] 0.96 1.06 0.98 1.08 1.09 0.90 1.01 1.08 1.01 0.99
```

Exact same list of values (as expected) as `replicate` is just a wrapper around sapply:

```
> replicate
function (n, expr, simplify = "array") 
sapply(integer(n), eval.parent(substitute(function(...) expr)), 
    simplify = simplify)
```

With a small test I can find a seed replicating your problem (I think):

```
for(i in 1000:2000) { 
  set.seed(i)
  if( all(replicate(10,sample(seq(from = 0.9, to = 1.1, by = 0.01), size=1, replace=T)) < 1 )) { 
    print(i)
    break
  }
}
```

Gives me 1887 and so:

```
> set.seed(1887)
> sample(seq(from = 0.9, to = 1.1, by = 0.01), size=1, replace=T)[1]
[1] 0.99
> sample(seq(from = 0.9, to = 1.1, by = 0.01), size=1, replace=T)[1]
[1] 0.92
> sample(seq(from = 0.9, to = 1.1, by = 0.01), size=1, replace=T)[1]
[1] 0.96
> sample(seq(from = 0.9, to = 1.1, by = 0.01), size=1, replace=T)[1]
[1] 0.99
> sample(seq(from = 0.9, to = 1.1, by = 0.01), size=1, replace=T)[1]
[1] 0.95
> sample(seq(from = 0.9, to = 1.1, by = 0.01), size=1, replace=T)[1]
[1] 0.99
> sample(seq(from = 0.9, to = 1.1, by = 0.01), size=1, replace=T)[1]
[1] 0.96
> sample(seq(from = 0.9, to = 1.1, by = 0.01), size=1, replace=T)[1]
[1] 0.93
> sample(seq(from = 0.9, to = 1.1, by = 0.01), size=1, replace=T)[1]
[1] 0.94
> sample(seq(from = 0.9, to = 1.1, by = 0.01), size=1, replace=T)[1]
[1] 0.99
> replicate(10,sample(seq(from = 0.9, to = 1.1, by = 0.01), size=1, replace=T))
 [1] 1.07 1.06 0.97 1.07 1.00 0.99 0.91 1.01 1.05 0.97
```

Comment: thanks. that's exactly what I see. so my understanding of the seed was wrong.

Comment: @Triam The seed is the random number generator state, setting it to a fixed value allow you to generate predictable random sequences. The documentation in `set.seed` give more details.

Comment: My assumption was that if I see the numbers in replicate, I would expect them in stepwise execution as replicate is not more than a convenience function around stepwise execution.

Comment: @Triam Note that I reset the seed between the stepwise calls and replicate calls (unless in the last step to show the continuous generation). Unless you start from a fixed seed, a new session will generate one from time and process ID at first need, usually giving a fairly rare case to generate the same sequence of random numbers.

Comment: And so your assumption is correct, if you start with the ssame seed you'll get the same numbers using replicate or repeating calls manually... (if it is not the case for your session, edit your question to show it)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the sequence creation which happened under digit constraints (options("digits"=2)). See here for an answer ["R seq function produces wrong result"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35994327/r-seq-function-produces-wrong-results/)