# R seq function produces wrong results

Tags: r, seq

It seems that one of my machines produces wrong results for seq function while another machine or the online r-fiddle (http://www.r-fiddle.org) interpreter give expected results. On the machine in question following happens:

```
seq(from = 1, to = 1.1, by = 0.01)
[1] 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.1 1.1 1.1 1.1 1.1
```

Changing the command slightly returns expected result

```
seq(from = 0.99, to = 1.1, by = 0.01)
[1] 0.99 1.00 1.01 1.02 1.03 1.04 1.05 1.06 1.07 1.08 1.09 1.10
```

As soon as I cross the "1" threshold, the wrong result occurs, e.g. same when I do from = 2.95 to = 3.1, etc. Not sure how to find an answer as I couldn't replicate the problem on my other machine or on r-fiddle. The problem persists even after restarting the pc.

R version 3.1.3 (2015-03-09)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
    [1] LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252
    [3] LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C
    [5] LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252

Comment: yes I restarted R and also pc.

Comment: What's the output of `.Options$digits`?

Comment: output .Options$digits = 2

Comment: I have global options: options("scipen"=100, "digits"=2)

Comment: Ha ha! Gotcha! Try `options(digits=7)` and you'll solve it.

Comment: oh god. it works. thanks a lot! I was going crazy. s.o. wants to post this answer for acceptance?

Comment: @nicola: I did not consider that as cause, I actually forgot about it. My stupidity.

Comment: Are you setting `options(digits = 2)` in your `.Rprofile`?  If so, I'm not sure that's such a good idea.

Comment: @Richard Scriven no it's an R markdown file and for nicer printing I had set it to digits = 2. I realize it's probably bad practice. I guess I should round instead where needed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have set the `digits` option too low:

```
options(digits=2)
seq(from = 1, to = 1.1, by = 0.01)
#[1] 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.1 1.1 1.1 1.1 1.1 1.1
options(digits=7)
seq(from = 1, to = 1.1, by = 0.01)
#[1] 1.00 1.01 1.02 1.03 1.04 1.05 1.06 1.07 1.08 1.09 1.10
```